# Realm Android: Async Transaction affect UI thread

Tags: android, database, asynchronous, realm, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm currently using realm to query RealmObjects to show them on a GoogleMap. I am performing the read and getting the RealmResults but I can't find a way to put the markers on the map from the UI thread. I'd prefer to do this with an async call because it causes ~150ms of lag on the UI thread.

```
public void loadLocations(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {

            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<LocationObject> locations = realm.where(LocationObject.class).findAll();
                for (LocationObject location: locations ) {
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(location.lat, location.long))
                }
            }
        });
}
```

How can I later access the RealmResults on the UI thread? Realm mentions that RealmObjects are thread confined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `RealmChangeListener`. The [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) illustrate this very clearly using the puppies example.

```
RealmResults<LocationObject> locations;

//...
    locations = realm.where(LocationObject.class).findAllAsync();

    locations.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<Person>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<LocationObject> locations) {
            googleMap.clear();
            for (LocationObject location: locations) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(location.lat, location.long));
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above basically do a query asynchronously to the Realm database and the `addChangeListener` registers a callback method to be invoked when the query is done and will be invoked in future query calls as well (Refer to the [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) for more info on this).

So, I would suggest running the code above in an `onStart` or `onResume` method and don't forget to remove the change listener on `onStop` or `onPause` method, like so:

```
locations.removeChangeListeners();
```

Lastly, don't forget to close realm. Hope it helps! Don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Ohhhhh so the change listener will be called when the initial "findAllAsync" transaction is completed and for every update afterwards. Great advice, thanks @andyaldoo

Comment: @JesusGarcia Exactly.